# Help identify these sets/bricks

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Some of these are sets and some are bricks. Sorry if the quality is bad, I can't get any other pictures.

Please note: 3 and 4 seems to be from the same build, although I cannot fully verify that.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**01)**  <strike>*Bionicle* piece ???</strike>

*[Part #98141 Minifigure, Weapon Crescent Blade, Serrated with Bar](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98141&name=Minifigure,%20Weapon%20Crescent%20Blade,%20Serrated%20with%20Bar&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Weapon%5D#T=S&C=115&O=%7B%22color%22:%22115%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)*, with an updated and correct answer provided by site member Phil B.

[image]

**02)** *[Part #4150 Tile, Round 2 x 2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4150&name=Tile,%20Round%202%20x%202&category=%5BTile,%20Round%5D#T=S&C=86&O=%7B%22color%22:%2286%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)*.

[image]

**3 + 4)** Hails from [*Set #76109 Quantum Realm Explorers*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76109-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).
[image]

The yellowed outlined pieces in **3** and **4** is *[Part #17485 Brick, Round 2 x 2 with Pin Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=17485&name=Brick,%20Round%202%20x%202%20with%20Pin%20Holes&category=%5BBrick,%20Round%5D#T=S&C=86&O=%7B%22color%22:%2286%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)*.[image]

*[HERE's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6uCZJ3LakEg)* a *Youtube* speed build on the piece breakdown/buildup of this design look you're interested in.

[image]

Comment: The first part is [98141 Minifigure Weapon Cresent Blade Serrated with Bar](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98141&name=Minifigure,%20Weapon%20Crescent%20Blade,%20Serrated%20with%20Bar&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Weapon%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).